# Looking for a way to substitute files in Gulp based on extension

Tags: gulp

I am looking at using Gulp as a build system for a project that will need to produce outputs for various platforms. For many platforms the source files will be the same, but some files may need to be different for each platform.  What I would like is to have the following files:

```
file1.js
file2.js
file2.platform1.js
file2.platform2.js
```

I would then like Gulp to select (depending on a variable in the task) the following files for a 'generic' build:

```
file1.js
file2.js
```

For a 'platform1' build:

```
file1.js
file2.platform1.js
```

And so on.  Is anyone aware of any plugins that may do this?

Comment: Those aren't the real file names, are they? Actually, you won't need a plugin for that, but you can create different globbing patterns to select that. Or you create a dedicated file list. Take a look at the [glob primer](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)

Comment: I'm not sure that globbing is the answer.  I want to use the 'generic' (no platform specification) UNLESS a platform specific version exists. I didn't want to go down the dedicated file list path, but it may be the only real option.  I looked at writing a plugin, but because gulp is stream-based, I'm not sure if you can get a list of all filenames and then change the source stream contents (only one file 'visible' at a time in the stream).